# DIfferent baud rates of 434 MHZ transceiver

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

What are the different baud rates that I can set for 434 MHZ Transmitter? (I am using Arduino UNO and RadioHead lib to change the baud rates)

Comment: does the transmitter actually have baud rate settings?

Comment: If your 434MHz transmitter actually uses UART, you would have to look into the datasheet. If it is just a part of the RadioHead library (it seems so for me), have you searched it's documentation?